# How to create datadog 'change alerts' using terraform?

Tags: terraform, datadog

I am trying to create a change [monitor using terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/monitor). To create a monitor that checks that overtime a count stays at 0 for example every day (the value will go up to one some times and get back to 0).

I found on the UI the capacity to create a `change alert`.

[image]

I cant seem to find a way to define the configuration for this type. Is terraform just supporting only a subset of the monitors? or does the query need to be change in some specific way that I cant find documentation for?.

Answer (score 0):

I've  stumbled upon this as well. I just figured out you have to **manually** create the monitor using "change alerts" then go to "manage monitors" page, open the one you just created and you'll see the query that starts with `change(...)`. Copy the whole query to the `query` field in your terraform config.